# Google API client (Python): is it possible to use BatchHttpRequest with ETag caching

Tags: python, google-api-client, httplib2, youtube-data-api

I'm using YouTube data API v3.

Is it possible to make a big `BatchHttpRequest` (e.g., see [here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/batch)) and also to use ETags for local caching at the `httplib2` level (e.g., see [here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/performance))?

ETags work fine for single queries, I don't understand if they are useful also for batch requests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR**:

- BatchHttpRequest cannot be used with caching

**HERE IT IS**:

**First lets see the way to initialize `BatchHttpRequest`:**

```
from apiclient.http import BatchHttpRequest

def list_animals(request_id, response, exception):
  if exception is not None:
    # Do something with the exception
    pass
  else:
    # Do something with the response
    pass

def list_farmers(request_id, response):
  """Do something with the farmers list response."""
  pass

service = build('farm', 'v2')

batch = service.new_batch_http_request()

batch.add(service.animals().list(), callback=list_animals)
batch.add(service.farmers().list(), callback=list_farmers)


batch.execute(http=http)
```

**Second lets see how `ETags` are used:**

```
from google.appengine.api import memcache
http = httplib2.Http(cache=memcache)
```

**Now lets analyze:**

Observe the last line of BatchHttpRequest example: **`batch.execute(http=http)`**, and now checking the [source code](https://github.com/google/google-api-python-client/blob/68bce4ea78c5cbb4578b8a380886d18b35156a10/googleapiclient/http.py#L1417) for execute, it calls `_refresh_and_apply_credentials`, which applies the http object we pass it.

```
def _refresh_and_apply_credentials(self, request, http):
    """Refresh the credentials and apply to the request.
    Args:
      request: HttpRequest, the request.
      http: httplib2.Http, the global http object for the batch.
    """
    # For the credentials to refresh, but only once per refresh_token
    # If there is no http per the request then refresh the http passed in
    # via execute()
```

Which means, execute call which takes in http, can be passed the ETag http you would have created as:

```
http = httplib2.Http(cache=memcache)
# This would mean we would get the ETags cached http
batch.execute(http=http)
```

**Update 1**:

Could try with a custom object as well:

```
from googleapiclient.discovery_cache import DISCOVERY_DOC_MAX_AGE
from googleapiclient.discovery_cache.base import Cache
from googleapiclient.discovery_cache.file_cache import Cache as FileCache

custCache = FileCache(max_age=DISCOVERY_DOC_MAX_AGE)
http = httplib2.Http(cache=custCache)
# This would mean we would get the ETags cached http
batch.execute(http=http)
```

Because, this is just a hunch on the comment in http2 lib:

```
"""If 'cache' is a string then it is used as a directory name for
        a disk cache. Otherwise it must be an object that supports the
        same interface as FileCache.
```

### **Conclusion Update 2:**

After again verifying the google-api-python source code, I see that, `BatchHttpRequest` is fixed with `'POST'` request and has a content-type of `multipart/mixed;..` - [`source code`](https://github.com/google/google-api-python-client/blob/6d7f655d572415d8d8c812f79e83a46557921a53/googleapiclient/http.py#L1261).

Giving a clue about the fact that, BatchHttpRequest is useful in order to `POST` data which is then processed down the later.

Now, keeping that in mind, observing what [`httplib2`](https://github.com/httplib2/httplib2/blob/master/python2/httplib2/__init__.py#L1381) `request` method uses: `_updateCache` only when following criteria are met:

1. Request is in `["GET", "HEAD"]` or `response.status == 303` or is a `redirect request`
2. ElSE -- `response.status in [200, 203] and method in ["GET", "HEAD"]`
3. OR -- `if response.status == 304 and method == "GET"`

**This means, `BatchHttpRequest` cannot be used with caching.**

Comment: Thanks for the answer but. I had already tried to mix BatchHttpRequest and ETag in the way you suggested but the memcache folder, with local copies, remains empty. This is very strange. I am not sure that ETag is compatibile with BatchHttpRequest. I mean: probably ETag cannot cache batches...

Comment: @superciccio14 then does this `http = httplib2.Http(cache=".cache")` (Accordidng to source: In the simplest case, you can just pass in a directory name, and a cache will be built from that directory) not help?

Comment: Just tried, but unfortunately didn't help. The `.cache` folder is properly created but it remains always empty. I think that ETag cannot work with batches. : (

Comment: So what happens if you just single query? does the .cache folder is created?

Comment: Yes, the folder is created but this time it is also filled with the cached files.

Comment: @superciccio14 just updated the answer, which what I felt, "can" be of help, because `google-api-python-client` have their own caching available and if we can just directly give an object

Comment: My problem is understanding if batches can be cached with Etag, regardless of whether we decide to store cache in an "object" or in a directory. It seems like no (ie my test with `http = httplib2.Http(cache=".cache")`). Probably Etags are designed to track the status of a resource but not of a collection of resources.

Comment: @superciccio14 added the latest findings.

Comment: Thanks, I read. I do not understand why `BatchHttpRequest` should be useful only with `POST`. In fact, I used it with `GET` and it worked. It batched a collection of many `list` requests in only one `HTTP/GET` request (without caching, of course).

Comment: @superciccio14 because, `BatchHttpRequest` will take your batch of `GET` http requests and keep track of all the requests by `POST` + `multipart/mixed`. They use `multipart/mixed` to create a batch of execution (like batch execute email attachment download). So, in that sense, `BatchHttpRequest` is on right track.

Comment: Got it. Basically `list` is translated into `POST` + `multipart/mixed` but `httplib2`'s `_updateCache` does not work with `POST`. The answer is definitely: _no caching_. : ( right?

Comment: @superciccio14 yes, definitely no caching for `POST` from httplib2. Which seems, like correct.